# Angular5 Material Data table filtering not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have a material Data-table called in my component where the data is being called from an API which is defined in a service and called in the component which is working fine but when I apply the Data-table with Filtering which is provided at the `material.io` is not working as expected for whatever reason I don't know the filter part doesn't work?

Can anyone please help?

There are no errors or anything unusual I have tried various ways of shuffling the code and searching for this problem still nothing found.

Here is my code of component TS :

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewAgentInformationDetailComponent } from '../view-agent-information-detail/view-agent-information-detail.component'
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Element } from '../userinfo';
import { InfoService } from '../info.service';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-agent-information',
  templateUrl: './view-agent-information.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-agent-information.component.scss']
})
export class ViewAgentInformationComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource;
  data: Element[];
  constructor(private router: Router, public Info: InfoService) { }

  displayedColumns = ['ViewOpt', 'CustID', 'PremiseID', 'Status', 'Market'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Info.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = data
      console.log("Data Source: ");
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    })
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.data = this.dataSource;
    console.log(this.data);
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  onSelect(element) {
    this.Info.changeData(element);
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/viewinfo', element.cust_id])
  }
}
```

[Here you can see what is happening the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehqjk.png)

Comment: Can you add html as well?

Comment: did you find a solution!?

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is with your datasource, except this it seems fine.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Info.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        // rather than this.dataSource = data;
        console.log("Data Source: ");
        console.log(this.dataSource);
    })
}
```

And in `HTML` you should use datasource like this:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Anshuman's answer, you might also need to override the `filterPredicate` of your `dataSource`. This allows you to customise your filtering system. Let's say you want the ability to filter by `Premise ID`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Info.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    });
    // Define filter function to look for 'premiseId'matches
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter): boolean {
      return data.premiseId.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import { ViewAgentInformationDetailComponent } from '../view-agent-information-detail/view-agent-information-detail.component'
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Element } from '../userinfo';
import { InfoService } from '../info.service';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-view-agent-information',
 templateUrl: './view-agent-information.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./view-agent-information.component.scss']
})
export class ViewAgentInformationComponent implements OnInit {

 dayaSource : MatTableDataSource<Element>;
 data: Element[];
 constructor(private router: Router, public Info: InfoService) { }

 displayedColumns = ['ViewOpt', 'CustID', 'PremiseID', 'Status', 'Market'];

 ngOnInit() {
   this.Info.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
     this.dataSource = data
     console.log("Data Source: ");
     console.log(this.dataSource);
   })
 }

 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
 }

 onSelect(element) {
   this.Info.changeData(element);
   this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/viewinfo', element.cust_id])
 }
}
```

Comment: this.dataSource.filter is not coming for me